# z/OS Unix System Services: $0 returns an empty value

Tags: mainframe

I am running a started task (BPXBATCH which starts a Java program), and in that started task it attempts to execute a shell script. That shell script has the following line:

```
PGM=$0
```

One would expect this to return the current shell. In this case it does not. It returns an empty value. I've verified that the ID running the started task has an OMVS segment and has a PROGRAM=/bin/sh attribute.

I have the program working fine on another LPAR, with the exact same started task JCL, same RACF profile, and same program. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

`$0` returns the name of the shell script which is the shell name if you run `echo $0` from a shell command line.

If you require the shell program name use `$SHELL`.

It's curious that $0 is blank. How are you running the shell script from Java? `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: its running as z/OS started task running BPXBATCH, which in turn starts a shell script that starts Java. The user ID associated with the started task has an OMVS segment with a PROCESS=/bin/sh attribute, but is a non-interactive log in, meaning it can only run as a started task.

Comment: Right, so `echo $0` should print the name of the shell script (not the shell). It shouldn't be blank. In your shell script enable tracing using `set -x` and post the results.